# Как справиться с проблемой: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, retrofit

Как справиться с проблемой при запросе на HTTPS ресурс с самостоятельной подпиской сертификата?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Comment: А где сертификат брали? Или сами сделали?

Comment: @KoVadim сами сделали.

Comment: тогда Вам нужно самому доверять своему сертификату. Гугление на тему "retrofit self signed cert" приводит к такому https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно ответу [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim), ответ из источника ([источник](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired)).

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

UserService userClient = retrofit.create(UserService.class);

Call<ResponseBody> call = userClient.profilePicture("https://revoked.badssl.com/");  
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Toast.makeText(BadSSLActivity.this, "got response" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(BadSSLActivity.this, "SSL error?" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```